# Typescript - Delay specifying generic type until calling function

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-generics

I'm trying to override an existing API by specifying a generic type to infer what key/value pairs I'm allowed to pass to the function, and of course for IntelliSense. (I'm using vue.js here, but that shouldn't matter.)

This is the generic interface:

```
export interface CreateElement<T> {
  (tag?: string | Component<any, any, any, any> | AsyncComponent<any, any, any, any> | (() => Component), children?: VNodeChildren): VNode;
  (tag?: string | Component<any, any, any, any> | AsyncComponent<any, any, any, any> | (() => Component), data?: VNodeData & { props?: T }, children?: VNodeChildren): VNode;
}
```

The original interface does not have `<T>` and only has `data?: VNodeData`.

My goal is to be able to call `h` (which is of type `CreateElement`) with a generic type, so that props is properly typed.

```
// Generic type 'CreateElement<T>' requires 1 type argument(s). ts(2314)
var h: CreateElement = __baseCreateElement // type of __baseCreateElment is CreateElement (without <T>)
```

This is how I intend to call the function:

```
h<IProps>(Test1, {
  props: {
    test: 'asdf',
    disabled: true
  },
}),
```

I created a small repro here: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5ABygHtCBnAfgC4dkBtAawgE9bywpQBzAXVrggWyAL4BufMgycqtbA2ZtkHLiD4ChoiSNy5QkWIhQAhOOQgBhKBAwQAogBsIAWwjgckggApM3dpx4AGmQEAAtgBwATaxAaZQC1ZAAfKSF6XgBKDRYJAm9ff1VuYMiMOFp0TGCwiOi3OJUeZNSWdKyW7V19aHgkZCsbSEcXNzAAHgAVAD4PPOQfOD94ourwqJiGhO5mwVbM7Ny8haXGtRKyirLkADI6YjJZZAnRVdqNwqaU3baD3B1dBAkEAcZChWgDWzDVzuAC88wA7qBIiR4VJyC0MgA6AD62IARmZLNZIU5oWA0chTOYIUNSaNdKExgAJCYAWQAMqhgAA3KGjKZeADkkR5guCeDm9wock8c2QIvIcDxTkitE4AFcILKdCJgoLIBxBRlcEA)

Comment: Just move the type parameter to the call signature inside the interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, you can move the type parameter to the call signature:

```js
interface CreateElement {
    (tag: string, children?: string | any[]): any;
    <T>(tag: string, data: Data & { props?: Partial<T> }, children?: string | any[]): any;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)